# Simplify regular expression for time literals (like "10h50m")

Tags: regex, parsing, time, lexical-analysis

I am writing lexer rules for a custom description language using [pyLR1](https://github.com/sebastianriese/pyLR1) which shall include time literals like for example:

```
10h30m     # meaning 10 hours + 30 minutes
5m30s      # meaning 5 minutes + 30 seconds
10h20m15s  # meaning 10 hours + 20 minutes + 15 seconds
15.6s      # meaning 15.6 seconds
```

The order of specification for hour, minute and second parts shall be fixed to `h`, `m`, `s`. To specify this in detail, I want the following valid combinations `hms`, `hm`, `h`, `ms`, `m` and `s` (with numbers between the different segments of course).
As a bonus the regex should check for decimal (i.e. non-natural) numbers in the segments and only allow these in the segment with least  significance.

So I have for all but the last group a number match like:

```
([0-9]+)
```

And for the last group even:

```
([0-9]*\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+(\.[0-9]*)?)  # to allow for .5 and 0.5 and 5.0 and 5
```

Going through all the combinations of h, m and s a cute little python script gives me the following regex:

```
(([0-9]*\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+(\.[0-9]*)?)h|([0-9]+)h([0-9]*\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+(\.[0-9]*)?)m|([0-9]+)h([0-9]+)m([0-9]*\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+(\.[0-9]*)?)s|([0-9]*\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+(\.[0-9]*)?)m|([0-9]+)m([0-9]*\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+(\.[0-9]*)?)s|([0-9]*\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+(\.[0-9]*)?)s)
```

Obviously, this is a little bit of horror expression. Is there any way to simplify this? The answer must work with pythons `re` module and I will also accept answers which do not work with `pyLR1` if its due to its restricted subset of regular expressions.

Comment: What kind of regex does the lexer understand? Full Python regular expressions or some restricted kind?

Comment: Its a bit restricted, but I think it can be expanded to Python regexes in certain areas if neccessary. I will also accept answers which work with python's `re` even if they do not (yet) work with pyLR1.

Comment: also, are strings like "10h30s" (ie ommiting minutes) allowed ?

Comment: @c00kiemon5ter Originally, they should not. However I think it would be okay if.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can factorise your regular expression, using the notation `h`, `m`, `s` to denote each of the subregexes, the most basic version is:

```
h|hm|hms|ms|m|s
```

which is what you have currently. You can break this into:

```
(h|hm|hms)|(ms|m)|s
```

and then pulling out `h` from the first expression and `m` from the second we get (using `(x|)` == `x?`):

```
h(m|ms)?|ms?|s
```

Continuing on we get to

```
h(ms?)?|ms?|s
```

which is probably simpler (and probably the simplest).

---

Adding in the regex `d` to denote decimals (as in `\.[0-9]+`), this could be written as

```
h(d|m(d|sd?)?)?|m(d|sd?)?|sd?
```

(i.e. at each stage optionally have either decimals, or a continuation to the next of `h` `m` or `s`.)

This would result in something like (for just hours and minutes):

```
[0-9]+((\.[0-9]+)?h|h[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?m)|[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?m
```

---

Looking at this, it might not be possible to get into a form ameniable for pyLR1, so doing the parsing with decimals in every spot and then a secondary check might be the best way to do this.

Comment: This does not cover the point with allowing decimal values (only) in the least significant segment, or am I wrong? I could, however, implement that in a later check (i.e. having matched the RE, I can try to cast the non-least-significant segments to integer).

Comment: Since there's the desire to distinguish the least significant value specially, I'd think about `(h?m)?S|h?M|H` (where the capitalized version is the one that allows decimals).

Comment: @DonalFellows, that's a much better way: factorise from the right instead of from the left. :)

Comment: (Also, @JonasWielicki, I've added in a possible solution for the decimals, it's not very nice though...)

Comment: +1 by me, I like the factorisation logic of both dbaupp and @DonalFellows

Comment: @DonalFellows: Your solution seems to work pretty nice. I'd like to give you credit for this one, but I'm afraid right now I cannot do that except by upvoting your comment (is there a way to collaborate on an answer credit-wise on SO?) ;). It aborts parsing after the first decimal, which is not perfect, but it is fine for me.

Comment: @Jonas I don't need the rep; it was just an observation based on dbaupp's answer. Myself, I'd actually try to avoid using REs for anything other than the first level of parse, leaving higher-level constraints until later in the tokenizer.

Answer (score 1):

the below representation should be understandable, I dont know the exact regex syntax you're using, so you have to "translate" to the valid syntax yourself.

your hours

```
 [0-9]{1,2}h
```

your minutes

```
[0-9]{1,2}m
```

your seconds

```
[0-9]{1,2}(\.[0-9]{1,3})?s
```

you want all those in order, and able to omit any of those (wrap with `?`)

```
([0-9]{1,2}h)?([0-9]{1,2}m)?([0-9]{1,2}(\.[0-9]{1,3})?s)?
```

this however matches things like: `10h30s`
that is valid combinations are `hms`, `hm`, **`hs`**, `h`, `ms`, `m` and `s`
or iow, minutes can be ommited, but still have hours and seconds.

the other problem is if the empty string is given, it is matched, as all three `?` make that valid. so you have to work around this somehow. hmm

---

looking at @dbaupp `h(ms?)?|ms?|s` you can take the above and match:

```
h: [0-9]{1,2}h
m: [0-9]{1,2}m
s: [0-9]{1,2}(\.[0-9]{1,3})?s
```

so you get to:

```
h(ms?)?: ([0-9]{1,2}h([0-9]{1,2}m([0-9]{1,2}(\.[0-9]{1,3})?s)?)?
  ms?  :              [0-9]{1,2}m([0-9]{1,2}(\.[0-9]{1,3})?s)?
   s   :                          [0-9]{1,2}(\.[0-9]{1,3})?s
```

all those OR'd together give you a big but easy to break down regex:

```
([0-9]{1,2}h([0-9]{1,2}m([0-9]{1,2}(\.[0-9]{1,3})?s)?)?|[0-9]{1,2}m([0-9]{1,2}(\.[0-9]{1,3})?s)?|[0-9]{1,2}(\.[0-9]{1,3})?s
```

which get you away with both the empty string problem *and* the match of **`hs`**.

---

looking at @Donal Fellows comment on @dbaupp answer, I'll also do `(h?m)?S|h?M|H`

```
(h?m)?s: (([0-9]{1,2}h)?[0-9]{1,2}m)?[0-9]{1,2}(\.[0-9]{1,3})?s
 h?m   :  ([0-9]{1,2}h)?[0-9]{1,2}m
 h     :   [0-9]{1,2}h
```

and merged together, you end up with something smaller than the above:

```
(([0-9]{1,2}h)?[0-9]{1,2}m)?[0-9]{1,2}(\.[0-9]{1,3})?s|([0-9]{1,2}h)?[0-9]{1,2}m|[0-9]{1,2}h
```

---

now we have to find a way to match `.xx` demical representation

Comment: Matching emptystring is a huge problem I'm afraid. It breaks the whole lexing stage. For other purposes this would probably be fine though, if you add the neccessary magic to get decimals to work for things like `10h15.2m`.

Comment: I just saw `to allow for .5`. I will think about it

Answer (score 1):

Here is a short Python expression [that works](http://regexr.com?31dn2):

```
(\d+h)?(\d+m)?(\d*\.\d+|\d+(\.\d*)?)(?(2)s|(?(1)m|[hms]))
```

Inspired by Cameron Martins [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11293445/107152) based on conditionals.

## Explained:

```
(\d+h)?                 # optional int "h" (capture 1)
(\d+m)?                 # optional int "m" (capture 2)
(\d*\.\d+|\d+(\.\d*)?)  # int or decimal 
(?(2)                   # if "m" (capture 2) was matched:
  s                       # "s"
| (?(1)                 # else if "h" (capture 1) was matched:
  m                       # "m"
|                       # else (nothing matched):
  [hms]))                 # any of the "h", "m" or "s"
```

Comment: This looks really nice. Its a pity that the `pyLR1` engine does not support back reference conditions.

Comment: @Jonas, too bad, altho I thought *"will also accept answers which do not work with `pyLR1`"* ;-)

Comment: yup, I just thought I'd add that :).

Comment: I'm accepting the answer by @dbaupp, as it does the trick and works the best for me. When writing the above sentence I assumed that it would maybe need something more ... trivial ;). Hope it's okay :)

Answer (score 0):

You may have hours, minutes, and seconds.

```
    /(\d{1,2}h)*(\d{1,2}m)*(\d{1,2}(\.\d+)*s)*/
```

should do the work. Depending on the regex library, you will get your items in order, or you will have to parse them further to check for h, m or s.

In this latter case, see also what is returned by

```
   /(\d{1,2}(h))*(\d{1,2}(m))*(\d{1,2}(\.\d+)*(s))*/
```

Comment: Doesn't this parse `10h10h10h`?

Comment: @dbaupp it does :(. Such a literal shall syntax-error while lexing/parsing the language.

Comment: Of course you have to bind this to the whole value: ^...$ - otherwise it would also parse "It is now 10h30m, good morning" :-) . Add a ^ at the beginning and a $ at the end to match the full value.

Comment: It is an regex in a lexer. The lexer cannot know that it has to abort after the first `h` if that's not in your regex.

Answer (score 0):

The last group should be:

```
([0-9]*\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?)
```

unless you want to match `5.`

---

You could use [regex ifs](http://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html), like so:

```
(([0-9]+h)?([0-9]+m)?([0-9]+s)?)(?(?<=h)(([0-9]*\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+(\.[0-9]*)?)m)?|(?(?<=m)(([0-9]*\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+(\.[0-9]*)?)s)?|\b(([0-9]*\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+(\.[0-9]*)?)[hms])?))
```

Here - http://regexr.com?31dmj

I havn't checked that this works, but it trys to match just integers for hours, minutes, then seconds first, then if the last thing matched is hours, it allows fractional minutes, otherwise if the last thing matched is minutes, it allows fractional seconds.

Comment: Your expression does not compile with pythons `re` module (and I'm fine with matching `5.`).

Comment: I said I havn't checked that it works, but the idea is there. Read the link I gave you.

Comment: And it wouldn't work with `hms` (when `s` has the decimal form), but good idea.

Comment: Yes it would/should (if I've got the if syntax correct). It will match hours and minutes in integer form, fail on the optional integer seconds, then the if statement would check the last thing matched was `m`, and then try to match fractional seconds.

Comment: Nope, in your expression there is no decimal form for `s` at all.

Comment: Next you should fix the decimal form hours, when only `h` is used that is. And conditionals work in Python 2.4 if used with backrefs, so you could make it work.